# Is there a way display cn=changelog in Directory Tree of OpenLDAP when exploring with and directory explorer like phpldapadmin?

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, openldap, rhel7

I have configured my changelog to get logged using this procedure :[This tutorial I followed to set up changelog](https://tylersguides.com/guides/openldap-audit-log-overlay/)

Now I have a ldif that is logging the changelog. But the requirement is to be able to see an ou cn=changelog is directory tree which can be used to see these changelogs while using any ldap explorer. I am not able to find any resource on how to do it. Please guide me. I have added a picture for the reference.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Z04.png)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the [slapo-accesslog(5)](https://openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-accesslog&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release&arch=default&format=html) overlay, which logs operations in an internal LDAP database.